# Infinite loop subset sum backtracking

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement my own version of the sum of subsets problem, using backtracking, to get all the possible solutions of obtaining a given sum from an array of elements. At the moment, I'm getting output stuck in an infinite, the output adds up to the sum that I want, but it exceeds the number of elements of a type available in the array. I'm not sure why this happens, because I put some stopping conditions. The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1024

int coins_array[] = {1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,10,10,10,10,10,15,15,15,15,15,15};
int N = sizeof(coins_array) / sizeof(coins_array[0]);
int S = 27, Sol[MAX], sum, sol;

int acceptable(int step)
{
    int i = 0, sum = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= step; i++)
    {
        sum += Sol[i];
    }
    if((sum <= S) && (step <= N))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int solution(int sum)
{
    if (sum == S)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void print_solution(int step)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1 ; i <= step ; ++i)
        printf("%d ",Sol[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

void back(int step)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Sol[step] = coins_array[i];
        sum += coins_array[i];

        if(acceptable(step) == 1)
        {
            if(solution(sum) == 1)
            {
                print_solution(step);
            }
            else
                back(step+1);
        }
        sum -= coins_array[i];

    }
}

int main()
{
    back(1);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Output (in an infinite loop):
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3
```

So, the numbers add up to the desired sum, however it exceeds the number of available 1's, and doesn't make use of 10 or 15. I ran to this in the debugger and I believe the problem for the loop is at `back(step+1)`. Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: OT: You have a global variable `sum` but also a local variable `sum` inside `acceptable`. That's not illegal but it's bad style and very confusing. Avoid global variables if possible. If you really, really need a global variable, you should give it a unique, special name that isn't used for any other variables

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I'm trying to learn the gnu debugger better. As I said, I already put the program through the debugger, but I don't really know why it's looping infinitely

Comment: Things to keep a look out for: Array index variables. Are all array indexes within bounds of your arrays? Another thing to look out for: Infinite recursion. Will the recursive `back(step+1)` calls ever stop? Is there perhaps a chance that `sum` will become *larger* than `S`? That means `solution(sum)` will never return `1`.

Comment: Another tip when it comes to debugging: Minimize the input set or values. Start with `S == 1` and see what happens when you step through the code. Continue with `S == 2`, `S == 3` etc., until it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this covers all problems in your code but it's at least its one bug that needs to be fixed.

Your current code uses the same coin several times. For instance if you set the target to be 2 (i.e. `S = 2`), your code will generate a solution where `coins_array[0]` is used twice.

This happens because your `back` function always starts looking at the `coins_array` from index zero.

```
void back(int step)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ^^^^^
        Always starting from zero is wrong
```

Instead you need to start from the "next unused" coin. Unfortunately your current code doesn't track that so you need to redesign your solution.

To show the above described problem I made some minor changes to your program - 1) Reduced the available coins 2) Changed the target value 3) Added an array to track which coin (aka index) was used 4) printed the index

So with these change your code looks like:

```
#define MAX 1024

int coins_array[] = {1,1,3};
int N = sizeof(coins_array) / sizeof(coins_array[0]);
int S = 2, Sol[MAX], IndexUsed[MAX], sum, sol;

int acceptable(int step)
{
    int i = 0, sum = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= step; i++)
    {
        sum += Sol[i];
    }
    if((sum <= S) && (step <= N))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int solution(int sum)
{
    if (sum == S)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void print_solution(int step)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1 ; i <= step ; ++i)
        printf("%d (%d) ",Sol[i], IndexUsed[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

void back(int step)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Sol[step] = coins_array[i];
        IndexUsed[step] = i; 
        sum += coins_array[i];

        if(acceptable(step) == 1)
        {
            if(solution(sum) == 1)
            {
                print_solution(step);
            }
            else
                back(step+1);
        }
        sum -= coins_array[i];

    }
}

int main()
{
    back(1);
    return 0;
}
```

and generates the output (with my comments added):

```
1 (0) 1 (0)  // Illegal - coin at index 0 used twice
1 (0) 1 (1)  // Legal   - coin at index 0 and 1 used to reach the sum 2
1 (1) 1 (0)  // Illegal - this combination have already been used 
1 (1) 1 (1)  // Illegal - coin at index 1 used twice
```

As you can see, your code prints 4 solutions but it should only have printed 1. As already stated, this happens because your code always start from index zero in the function `back`